# UDP SocketException on EndReceiveFrom (C#)

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I'm currently writing some async UDP network code in C#. I'm sending small packets (less than 50 bytes of data in each so far) back and forth and my first thought was to split them into two different packets and still send it as one packet but receive it as two. So a header or an extra information packet is always added to the start of the real packet. That would contain an ID and the data length.

So I thought I could split it on the receiving end (async receive) and first receive the header and then the actual information. This is so that I don't have to worry about the order between packets and "packet headers".

So I wrote code that basically worked like this:
Client sends 30 bytes of data to the server, where the first 3 bytes is the packet header.

The server would have called (PACKET_HEADER_SIZE = 3):

```
socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, 0, PACKET_HEADER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint, ReceivePacketInfo, state);
```

Then receives the data:

```
private void ReceivePacketInfo(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObj state = (StateObj) ar.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref endPoint);
    state.BytesReceived += read;
    if (state.BytesReceived < state.Buffer.Length)
    {
        _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.Buffer, state.BytesReceived, state.Buffer.Length - state.BytesReceived, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint, ReceivePacketInfo, state);
    }
    else
    {
        //my thought was to receive the rest of the packet here
    }
}
```

but when calling socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar) I get a SocketException:

"A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some    other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself"

So now I have a couple of questions.

Do I have to make sure I receive the whole packet (in this case both the header and the packet) before I call EndReceiveFrom?

Can I assume that I will either get the whole packet in one go or get nothing so that my if-statement in ReceivePacketInfo would be redundant (as long as it's size is less than the maximum packet size, of course)?

If I cannot, is there a good way of solving my problem? I could tag all my packet headers and all my packets to be able to map them together I suppose. I could also try to have a standardized "packet ending" so that I just read until I hit the end of the packet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I assume that I will either get the whole packet in one go or get nothing

That's almost the only thing, that UDP can guarantee - the content of a packet. If packet is received it is guaranteed to have same size and same content. So you have to make sure, that you buffer is large enough for a packet.

The order of a packets is not guaranteed and the delivery itself. It is up to you and your application to handle dropped packets and out of order packets.